# Como testar o segundo valor de entrada de um usuario no c#

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft

quero testar o ultimo WriteLine dessa funcao:

```
public void SendEmail()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Gostaria de receber seu diamante por e-mail?");
    Console.WriteLine("Digite s para 'SIM' e n para 'Nao'...");
    string input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    while (input != "s" && input != "n")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite s para 'SIM' e n para 'Nao'...");
        input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Por favor, informe seu e-mail");
    string emailUser = Console.ReadLine();
    EmailUser = emailUser;
    Console.WriteLine($"Um e-mail foi enviado para {emailUser}");
}
```

como faco para passar do primeiro input e e testar o segundo?

```
[Theory(DisplayName = "Deve Validar se o e-mail foi enviado")]
[InlineData("Rafael", "Um e-mail foi enviado para Rafael")]
[InlineData("Richarlisson", "Um e-mail foi enviado para Richarlisson")]
public void TestSendEmail(string entry, string expectMessage)
{
    using(var output = new StringWriter())
    {
        using( var input = new StringReader(entry))
        {
            Console.SetOut(output);
            Console.SetIn(input);
            var instanceDiamond = new Diamond();
            instanceDiamond.SendEmail();
            var response = output.ToString().Trim().Split('\n');
            response[^1].Should().Be(expectMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: É recomendável editar a pergunta e esclarecer o que significa "passar do primeiro input e e testar o segundo".

Answer (score -1):

Fazendo uns testes descobri que o Console.SetIn está 1 para 1 para o Console.ReadLine.

Isso significa que para simular sua aplicação você teria que executar o Console.SetIn, executar o Console.ReadLine, depois executar novamente o Console.SetIn e por fim o Console.ReadLine.

Existe uma alternativa que é a criação de um wrapper (encapsulador) do Console.

```cs
public interface IProviderIO
{
    void WriteLine(string text);
    string? ReadLine();
}

public class ProviderIO : IProviderIO
{
    public void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public string? ReadLine()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Feito isso, precisamos mudar a implementação da sua classe Diamond:

```cs
public class Diamond
{
    private readonly IProviderIO providerIO;

    public Diamond(IProviderIO providerIO)
    {
        this.providerIO = providerIO;
    }

    public void SendEmail()
    {
        providerIO.WriteLine("Gostaria de receber seu diamante por e-mail?");
        providerIO.WriteLine("Digite s para 'SIM' e n para 'Nao'...");

        string input = providerIO.ReadLine().ToLower();
        while (input != "s" && input != "n")
        {
            providerIO.WriteLine("Digite s para 'SIM' e n para 'Nao'...");
            input = providerIO.ReadLine().ToLower();
        }
        providerIO.WriteLine("Por favor, informe seu e-mail");
        string emailUser = providerIO.ReadLine();
        providerIO.WriteLine($"Um e-mail foi enviado para {emailUser}");
    }
}
```

E para testar, podemos utilizar a biblioteca Moq:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData("s", "email@email.com", "Um e-mail foi enviado para email@email.com")]
public void TestSendEmail(string confirmation, string email, string expected)
{
    // Arrange
    var mockProvider = new Mock<IProviderIO>(); // Criamos o Mock da interface IProviderIO

    // Configuramos o comportamento do método ReadLine
    mockProvider.SetupSequence(x => x.ReadLine())
        // Quando o método for chamado pela 1ª vez, será retornado o valor da variável confirmation
        .Returns(confirmation)
        // E quando o método for chamado pela 2ª vez, será retornado o valor da variável email
        .Returns(email);

    // Feito a configuração do mock, podemos repassá-lo para a classe Diamond
    var diamond = new Diamond(mockProvider.Object);

    // Act
    diamond.SendEmail();

    // Assert
    // Verificamos se o método WriteLine foi invokado 1 vez com o valor da variável expected
    mockProvider.Verify(x => x.WriteLine(expected), Times.Once());
}
```

Feito isso agora só é necessário criar mais cenários de teste.